# how to remove query string from url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Once my friend help me to solve this issue, I have written code like that. Where `example.com/blog-detail?slug=slugvalue` it goes to `blog-detail.php` and this url `example.com/project?slug=test` goes to `project.php`.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Checking condition and getting matches in variables to be used while redirect in next rule.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^?]*)\?slug=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$  blog-detail.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I think it's work for only blog-detail page now i face the issue with this url
https://www.example.com/project?slug=test, it redirect me to 404 page, could you help me here.

Comment: Thanks for sharing efforts, could you please do mention which request should go to blog.php? and which request should go to other php file?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 http://example.com/blog-detail?slug=slugvalue it goes to blog-detail.php  and  this url https://www.example.com/project?slug=test goes to project.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts; please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

I have added 2 solutions here, so either use 1st rules set OR use 2nd rules set ONLY ONE at a time please.

***1st solution:*** With 2 different rules set for each php file please try following rules.

```
RewriteEngine ON
###Rules for blog-detail.php redirect and rewrite.
##Checking condition and getting matches in variables to be used while redirect in next rule.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(blog-detail)\?slug=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$  blog-detail.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]

###Rules for project.php redirect and rewrite.
##Checking condition and getting matches in variables to be used while redirect in next rule.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(project)\?slug=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$  project.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** A Generic solution with capturing groups to deal with both kind of php files together.

```
RewriteEngine ON
###Rules for blog-detail.php OR project.php redirect and rewrite.
##Checking condition and getting matches in variables to be used while redirect in next rule.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^?]*)\?slug=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$  /$1.php?slug=$2 [QSA,L]
```

***NOTE1:*** Please keep both your php files(`project.php` and `blog-detail.php`) should be kept along with your htaccess rules file.

***NOTE2:*** For JS/CS rewrite/redirect:
You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: First solution is only work for blog-details page not working for project and if i use second solution then both url goes to 404 page

Comment: @KunalVerma, please check my 2nd solution once now, I edited it now, there was a typo, let me know how it goes. Make sure both php files are residing along with your htaccess file.

Comment: Now page is working fine but redirection not apply

Comment: both url open with slug

Comment: @KunalVerma, ok, I have added 1 more condition in my both of solutions, kindly do check it once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Both Solution working same url redirect with slug

Comment: @KunalVerma, could you please confirm your both php files are present along with htaccess file? And then show me samples urls which you are hitting and what they are becoming in browser too, thank you.

Comment: Yes both file are present along with htaccess file here is the url please check https://www.beyondmaids.com/blog-detail?slug=test

Comment: @KunalVerma, these rules are well tested and they should work well, not sure why they are not working. Again keep only these rules and try with cleaning cache, because they work on my localhost when I test them.

Comment: I do same as you said but it's not working

Comment: @KunalVerma, you don't have any other rules right? OR any other htaccess apart from this? Please confirm once.

Comment: same code present which i mention is last question but redirection rule is one of yours and no other htaccess file present

Comment: @KunalVerma, ok, I have made 1 more change in rules, please do check once and let me know how it goes then? Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: No it's not working i think in ans tab same code is present as old can you please check at your end if bot ans are updated or not

Comment: @KunalVerma, yeah they are updated. Ok try 2nd solution's last line changing, change it from `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$  $1.php?slug=$2 [QSA,L]` TO `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$   /$1.php?slug=$2 [QSA,L]` apart from that keep it like that way itself and let me known then.

Comment: Code is working but it can't redirect to correct url I mean

Comment: I mean by default this url is open https://www.beyondmaids.com/blog-detail?slug=test if i remove slug from url https://www.beyondmaids.com/blog-detail/test and hit enter it's working as well can you understand what i say

Comment: code can't directly open this url https://www.beyondmaids.com/blog-detail/test

Comment: @KunalVerma, my rules are supposed to work for url `https://www.beyondmaids.com/blog-detail?slug=test` only. Do you want it to hit `https://www.beyondmaids.com/blog-detail/test` in browser also?

Comment: No i want if i hit this url https://www.beyondmaids.com/blog-detail?slug=test then by defaut open url like this https://www.beyondmaids.com/blog-detail/test

Comment: but now your code can't redirect to this url https://www.beyondmaids.com/blog-detail/test but page is working on both url

Comment: @KunalVerma, I understand your problem but I am sorry can't help on this one since these rules are working for me on my localhost. What further I could say is, you can check apache logs, without seeing system its difficult to troubleshoot honestly.

Comment: How i solve this

Comment: @KunalVerma, as mentioned earlier check apache logs once, you can read documentation where to check apache logs, without seeing system its difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: I have solve the issue made some changes on you code

Comment: Can I send you the code

Comment: @KunalVerma, oh great, please edit my answer(only fixed part please) so that future users can be benefited from it. Please Edit my answer and I will approve it.

Comment: I have update the second solution please check and approve it